# Javadoc @param with -

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm making javadoc:

```
/**
 * make Something
 *
 * @param value - blabla( I´m using @param value - blabla, instead @param
 * value blabla)
 * @return something
 */
public String makeSomething(String value) {

    return "";
}
```

Should I use `@param value` - or just `@param value`?

Comment: I think typically you would omit the hypen. When generating the actual Javadoc, everything after the parameter name is the description, so using a hyphen would add the hyphen to the start of your description.

Comment: Using @param value- with value description is a good documentation options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most doclets introduce a hypen between the `@param` tag and the parameter's name. Adding another hypen yourself will cause an ugly, double hypen to be rendered.